# Numpy: Storing array of different sizes into 2-D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the code below

```
import numpy as np
U = np.zeros((n,m))
for i in range(n):
    u = zeros(m-i)
    U[i] = u
```

where I'd like the output to be `U = [[0,0,...(m times)],...,[0,0,...,(m-n+1 times)]]`

How can that be easily achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
arr = [[0 for _ in range(m - i)] for i in range(n)]
U = np.array(arr, dtype=object)
```